# Carbon laravel creates different value on controller and on queue(Job class)

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I have simple code using Carbon on Laravel as follow:

```
    $dt = Carbon::now();
    $user_log = new UserLog;
    $user_log->created = $dt->toDateTimeString();
    $user_log->save();
```

And the result is different in controller and in class queue process(ex : class Task extends Job implements ShouldQueue)

result :

```
2016-04-20 14:32:02 // my setting timezone that i want
2016-04-20 07:32:05 //UTC (ON queue process)
```

anyone have clue about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dt = Carbon::now()->setTimezone('Asia/Jakarta');
```

i just put that setTimezone on my queue job and problem solved

Comment: Problem temporarily solved. Will you include that timezone everywhere you need handling of dates in php queues? IMHO, change the timezone in your php.ini for both CLI and php-fpm. See: https://www.siteground.com/kb/datetimezone_value_in_php/

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that Laravels queue is using the command line version of PHP, which happens to be different to whatever apache/nginx is serving.

On the command line you can use the following command to find your PHP version:

```
php --version
```

This should give you some output like below:

```
PHP 5.5.22 (cli) (built: Mar  9 2015 21:14:11)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

In your laravel app echo `phpinfo()` and see if the version matches the output from the command line.

Comment: on production environtment, im using ubuntu nginx, with beanstalkd, and supervisor @Jeemusu

Comment: Same line of thinking, check to see if your CLI version of PHP is the same as the one nginx is using.

Comment: its the same @Jeemusu

Comment: @rizky redjo In that case make sure your PHP, Laravel and nginx all have the same timezone in their config files.

Comment: I am pretty sure change everything to my timezone(PHP, laravel, nginx, ubuntu), but the the queue process save different timezone. @Jeemusu

Comment: Somewhere in your application stack, something is set to use UTC timezone, if it's not PHP, Laravel, NGINX or Ubuntu, then I'm not too sure what could be causing it. Debug each one and make sure the output timezone is what you expect.